# Network request intermittently failing with error -1009 The internet connection appears to be offline

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have multiple request that I call on the viewDidLoad method of my initial view controller. Sometimes these requests are failing with `Error Code -1009 The internet connection appears to be offline.` for some user and others are not having it. Sometimes users who get the error can use it after sometime with no issues. This usually happens on a cellular network. And other apps are working in their phone and not ours.

All of these requests are using the same method on my Service class. First I have an enum of the APIs and I convert them to a URLRequest using Alamofire's URLRequestConvertible protocol. Then I pass this request into Alamofire and handle the response.

```
func get<T:Codable>(_ api: ServiceAPI, resultType: T.Type, completion: @escaping (_ result: T?, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {
    Alamofire.request(api).validate().responseJSON { response in
      switch response.result {
      case .success(let json):
        print("\(api.path):\n\(json)")
        do {
          if let data = response.data {
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            let dictionary = try jsonDecoder.decode([String: T].self, from: data)
            if let result = dictionary["result"] {
              completion(result, nil)
            } else {
              completion(nil, self.resultNotFoundError)
            }
          }
        } catch {
          completion(nil, error)
        }
      case .failure(let error):
        error.trackMixPanelEvent()
        completion(nil, error)
      }
    }
  }
```

Since I am creating an instance of the Service class and calling the get method on it for each request, is it possible that the request is being deallocated? What could also be the cause of such intermittent network error?

To also point out, all of the web service requests are using POST method.

Comment: If error is -1009, then it's not due to deallocation.